# Showing a .swf file in a WebView

Tags: java, android, swfobject

can somebody help me please to show a .swf file into a WebView, I tried to do, but it shows a white windows instead of WebView. Also I tried to show a simple website and it shows also a empty window.

**Fragment.java**

```
package com.app.clupascu.oavm;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {


    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);

        String url ="file:///android_asset/map.swf";
        WebView mWebView=(WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        mWebView.loadUrl(url);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);

    }
}
```

Here I tried to load the .swf file into WebView.
I thought that the problem is in this file and I tried to load a simple website, but also without result.

**Fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainPage.java**

```
package com.app.clupascu.oavm;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainPage extends AppCompatActivity {


    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    setTitle("Map");
                    FirstFragment fragment = new FirstFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fram, fragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    setTitle("History");
                    SecondFragment fragment2 = new SecondFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction2 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction2.replace(R.id.fram, fragment2);
                    fragmentTransaction2.commit();
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                    setTitle("Schedule");
                    ThirdFragment fragment3 = new ThirdFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction3 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction3.replace(R.id.fram, fragment3);
                    fragmentTransaction3.commit();
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);

        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

        setTitle("Map");
        FirstFragment fragment = new FirstFragment();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fram, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: check if webview variable is holding null or not

Comment: I think you are missing this: "mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
"

Answer (score 1):

SWF is a ShockWaveFlash file. Web browsers can not run/display a ShockWave Flash File without the help of the Flash Plugin.

The Flash Plugin for Android has been discontinued several years ago. Therefore you won't succeed in making it run in a WebView.

Hence you have to re-think your application design and how you can achieve whyt you want without that SWF file.

Anyway it is not a good idea to start a new app using a technology the will reach its [end of life in 2 years (end of 2020)](https://theblog.adobe.com/adobe-flash-update/).